# How to place a popup message in center of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div block for which I am calculating its width and offset height on the basis of the calculation below. Now I am trying to place the message holder block inbetween the div block.

My aim is to show the message "popup" block in the center of the div "oID_1". Can anybody help me?

```
<BODY>
  <head>
  <script>
  function msgBox(message) {
    var msgbox = document.getElementById("msgbox");
    msgbox.innerHTML = message;
    var x = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (msgbox.offsetWidth / 2);
    var y = (window.offsetHeight / 2) - (msgbox.offsetHeight / 2);              
    msgbox.style.top = y;
    msgbox.style.left = x;
    msgbox.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .popup {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid green;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showPopup(id) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(id);
    var divblock=document.getElementById('oID_1');
    width=parseInt(oID_1.style.width);
    var x = (width / 2) - (popup.offsetWidth / 2);
    var y = (divblock.offsetHeight / 2) - (popup.offsetHeight / 2);              
    popup.style.top = y;
    popup.style.left = x;
    popup.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
</head>
<DIV CLASS="body">
  <center>
  <div id="popup" class="popup">
    This a vertically and horizontally centered popup.
  </div>
  <a onclick="showPopup('popup');">Show Popup</a>
  <DIV ID="oID_1" STYLE=" width:300; height:300;border:1px solid red">
  </DIV>
  </center>
</DIV> 
</BODY>
```

Comment: Why do you have a head tag inside body?

Comment: In the center of what div now, the "oID_1" element has no position and is only 2px high, how do expect to center an element inside that? And those `<center>` tags should'nt be used either and your head is inside your body. You need to go back to the basics, and learn basic HTML and CSS first.

Comment: @AaditMShah your sol doesn't help...would you stop asking about acceptance

Comment: @KunalVashist - Perhaps you would elaborate why it doesn't help and what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: @KunalVashist - I would really appreciate if you took the time to answer me. I spent a lot of time and effort into trying to help you.

Comment: @AaditMShah by requirement was something else. and you ans was something different...

Comment: @KunalVashist - Care to explain your requirement vs my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If your element is absolute positioned and you know it's width, you can always use left: 50%; margin-left: -(half width)px

Comment: i even tried that in css added top:50%; left:50%; but that too doesn't help in my case

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28Dgj/ you have some mistakes in you styles, like #OID_1 height has no px

Comment: I did that now if i clicked twice the div block gets changed .on first click it gets centered

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? 
Take a look at [center-div-with-jquery](http://manos.malihu.gr/center-div-with-jquery)

Comment: I don't want to center the div i want that popup message to be centered inside the div

Comment: Center inside a windows or inside a DIV is almost the same. The theoretical concepts behind it are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following website: http://bushraaadit.appspot.com/

Now the way they have centered the div is quite simple. First we'll take a look at the HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay so we have three nested divs. The first one (the `container`) is the div within which you want to center the third div (`center`). The second div (the `wrapper`) is used to help center it. Think of it as a center tag which centers horizontally and vertically.

Now for the CSS (yes it works purely on CSS and automatically re-centers itself when the `container` div is resized). Give the `container` div any width and height you want. Now for the `wrapper` and the `center` divs.

The `wrapper` div **must have** the same width and height as the `center` div. If the `center` div needs an explicit width and height (say 50% of the container) then set it on the `wrapper` and set the width and height of the `center` as 100% (which is 100% of 50% of the container). Otherwise make the `wrapper` float to the left (doing so will automatically shrink it to the size of the `center` div).

Finally to center it we first set the position of the `wrapper` and `center` to relative. Then the `wrapper` div is positioned 50% to the right and the bottom from where it is (50% of the container). Then the `center` div is positioned 50% to the left and top from where it is (50% of the `wrapper` which is 50% of itself).

The resulting CSS is something like:

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    background-color: #FFF0F5;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

#center {
    background-color: #FFE4E1;
    bottom: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The end result can be seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3kVj/

Hope that helps.